# Prove that for any $g\in G$ and $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $g^{m}g^{n}=g^{m+n}$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, exponentiation

Can someone please tell me if my solution is okay?

> Prove that for any $g\in G$ and $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $g^{m}g^{n}=g^{m+n}$.

Case 1: $m,n>0$

$g^{m}g^{n}=g\cdot g\cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($m$ $g$'s) $\cdot g \cdot g \cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($n$ $g$'s) $=g\cdot g\cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($m+n$ $g$'s) $=g^{m+n}$

Case 2: $m,n<0$

$g^{-m}g^{-n}=(g^{-1})^{m}(g^{-1})^{n}=g^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}\cdot \cdots \cdot g^{-1}$ ($m$ $g^{-1}$'s) $\cdot g^{-1} \cdot g^{-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot g^{-1}$ ($n$ $g^{-1}$'s) $=g^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}\cdot \cdots \cdot g^{-1}$ ($m+n$ $g^{-1}$'s) $=(g^{-1})^{m+n}=g^{-m-n}$

Case 3: $m>0$ and $n<0$

$g^{m}g^{-n}=g^{m}(g^{-1})^{n}=g\cdot g\cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($m$ $g$'s) $\cdot g^{-1} \cdot g^{-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot g^{-1}$ ($n$ $g^{-1}$'s) $=g\cdot g\cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($m-n$ $g$'s by cancellation laws) $=g^{m-n}$

Case 4: $m<0$ and $n>0$

$g^{-m}g^{n}=(g^{-1})^{m}g^{n}=g^{-1}\cdot g^{-1}\cdot \cdots \cdot g^{-1}$ ($m$ $g^{-1}$'s) $\cdot g \cdot g \cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($n$ $g$'s) $=g\cdot g\cdot \cdots \cdot g$ ($n-m$ $g$'s by cancellation laws) $=g^{n-m}=g^{-m+n}$

Comment: It is okay. People will understand what you mean. Now try organizing it to make apparent how induction is being used.

Comment: @cactus: I don't think it *is* being used.

Comment: @CameronBuie I believe that was his point.

Comment: @CMonsour: So I gathered, but I wonder if it's really necessary, here.

Comment: @CameronBuie Among friends, no.  For a formal proof, yes.

Comment: @CameronBuie It is not used because strictly speaking the proof is not properly written. It is necessary, since no group axiom or combination of them has or produces a $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$ in the proposition.

Comment: @CMonsour: I think we may have to agree to disagree on that one. If there are $m$ $g$'s to the left and $n$ $g$'s to the right, with nothing in between, all of which are multiplied? That is definitionally $m+n$ $g$'s multiplied together, which is denoted by $g^{m+n}.$

Comment: @cactus: Neither does any group axiom (or combination thereof) say anything about $g^n.$ That is from a definition apart from the axioms.

Comment: @CameronBuie You'll have a lot of writing to do.  I think you missed the universal quantifier at the start of the question!  (I'm not disputing that you could do the proof your way for specific values of $m$ and $n$.  But that requires a new proof for each pair of values.)

Comment: @CMonsour: Did I? I believe that in each case, $m$ and $n$ are arbitrarily chosen from the specified subsets of $\Bbb Z.$ In fact, the *only* flaw I see in the proof is that it doesn't cover the cases in which $m=0$ and/or $n=0.$

Comment: @CameronBuie Exactly, $g^n$ is defined for all $n$, using induction. You are confused about the proof being correct. The "$...$ ($m$ g's)" is not in the language. You cannot write the expression you want for arbitrary $m,n$.

Comment: @cactus: Yes, induction has already been used to define it. This does not mean that induction need be invoked every time $g^n$ is used. However, I see your point. See my answer below, and let me know what you think.

Comment: Okay! After doing some searching, I realized that induction would be the best way for a formal proof. I will definitely give it a try. :)

Comment: If we are proving a proof this basic I think we should state that $(\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{n times})(\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{m times})=(\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{n times}\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{m times})$ by associativity.  I do *not* think $\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{n times}\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{m times}=\underbrace{g\cdot g\cdot ... \cdot g}_{n + mtimes}$ needs to be proven at all.  Unless this is a course that incudes the peano axioms.

Comment: "Neither does any group axiom (or combination thereof) say anything about gn. That is from a definition apart from the axioms."  I've always interpretted the definition $g^n$ as "because of associativity and closure $((...((g)\cdot g)\cdot ....) $ is distinct and $g^n:=\underbrace{g\cdot...\cdot g}_{ntimes}$ is unambiguous and well defined"  And as an imediate consequence $g^ng^m = g^{n+m};n,m \in \Bbb N$ by definition needing no proof other than citing "n iterations followed by m iterations is n+m iterations" by definition of addition. (OUTSIDE course scope!)

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, by associativity, closure, *and induction,* it's easily and unambiguously proved to be defined. Also, I don't get the last part, where you yell a sentence fragment in parentheses....

Comment: I was running out of characters.  My point is proving that addition on integers exists and is consistent and the doing something m times and then doing it n times means you did it m+n times is well out of the scope of the class unless they are doing some very intensive constructivism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is "okay," certainly, but you haven't covered all your bases.

In particular, you leave out every case in which at least one of $m,n$ is equal to $0.$

As pointed out in the comments above, there are those (perhaps including the person grading your assignment) who will (in my opinion, unnecessarily) insist on induction being used in the proof. I will agree that induction makes the proof *easier*, but I won't insist that it's necessary. However, I will admit that "$\dots$" gets in the way, here. It would be better to put it into words. For example, we might instead say (in case $1$): "$g^mg^n$ is simply the product of $m$ $g$'s and $n$ $g$'s, or of $m+n$ $g$'s, which is simply $g^{m+n}.$"

Comment: Thank you! Okay, I didn't realize induction should be used, I will give it a try :)